# undefined method `css' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri, xml-parsing

Im receiving this error in my Rails app and cant find the solution. I will add some code from the class where it fails. It might be a more of an architectural problem if you think so please do say and I will add more code from other classes. I basically only have this model, and one controller and another class which is located in lib. An then a view of course. Thanks in advance!

```
  #app/models/news_api.rb
  require 'open-uri'

  class NewsApi
    URL = "http://www.mysomething.com/partner/api/1_0/somerandomnumber/
          channel/290/material/list/"

  def self.download
   new.document.css('news').map {|node| record(node) } 
  end

  def document
    Nokogiri::XML(open(URL)) 
    puts URL.to_s
  end

  def record(node)
    Story.new(node_to_hash(node)) 
  end

  def node_to_hash(node)
    Hash[Story::ATTRIBUTES.collect {|attribute| [attribute, text(node, attribute)] }]
  end

  def text(node, selector)
   node.css(selector).text
  end
end
```

@idlefingers: Here is the code from my view. What Im doing is basically using Nokogiri to parse some xml from an API and then displaying the response in HTMl in my view.

```
<ul id="news">
 <% @stories.each do |story| %>
 <li class=" <%= story.type_of_media %>">
  <h2><%= link_to story.header, story.url %></h2>
  <p class="permalink"><%= link_to 'Trackback', story.url %></p>
  <p class="meta">
    <strong><%= story.source_name %></strong>
    <br/>
    <%= story.created_at %>
    <br/>
    <%= story.geo %>
  </p>
  <p class="summary"><%= story.summary %></p>
 </li>
```

<% end %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the error coming from? At a glance, it looks like it's coming from the `.document` method, but it isn't clear. Can you add the error backtrace?

The `.document` method as it stands will be returning the result of `puts URL.to_s`, which will be nil. You just need to switch around the two lines in your `.document` method by the looks of it...

```
def document
  puts URL.to_s
  Nokogiri::XML(open(URL)) 
end
```

Comment: Remember that in Ruby, the last expression is what is returned implicitly

Comment: @idlefingers: Thanks that actually got me pass that problem but Im back at my initial problem which was that i for some reason couldnt display the xml response in my view. Please see my additional code above from above. Thank you!

Comment: What isn't working? You need to provide more info of what the actual error is.

Comment: Well when I inspect the view in my browser my <li> is not displayed which is extremely weird. After <ul> it is not displayed. It think my view is pretty straight forward but I think I have stared myself blind looking at it too much. Can you see anything? Right now I have no error but it just seems empty.

Comment: It means `@stories` must be an empty array. Check that your scraping the html correctly and that the elements exist on the page you're scraping. Maybe give it a try in the console and check whether you're getting what you're expecting back from nokogiri.